# SSH HTTP tunnel not working

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling, http

I'm trying to learn how to use SSH tunnels. For this, I took two VPS. I want to forward http traffic from vps-1 through vps-2. I tried to configurate tunnels by

- `ssh -L 80:127.0.0.1:80 ramirag@95.216.151.169`
- `ssh -L 80:icanhazip.com:80 ramirag@95.216.151.169`
- `ssh -L 80:localhost:80 ramirag@95.216.151.169`

For testing i use `wget -O - -q icanhazip.com`. But at any case i receive vps-1 ip. What I missed?

Comment: Possibly related - https://superuser.com/q/96489/20568

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SSH tunneling is not intended for this purpose. For example, the first tunnel you mentioned would cause :

```
wget http://localhost/
```

on VPS-1 to open a connection to local 80 port, forwarded to 95.216.151.169 where it would open the local 80 port. This would be equivalent to doing " wget http://95.216.151.169/ ".

If you actually want VPS-1 web traffic going through VPS-2 you should setup a http proxy (such as [squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/)), and then use this proxy in your browser or wget command.

Alternatively - to forward any internet traffic - you could setup a VPN server 
on VPS-2 (e.g. openvpn-as)

Comment: Thx. I understood the task of the SSH tunnel.